# Moving files to corresponding subdirectory in Python

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, directory, subdirectory

Every week at work, I am responsible for manually moving 100-200 files from one folder into a corresponding subfolder. After doing this for a couple of weeks, I thought to myself: This can be done faster!

I have used Python 2.7 and 3.X a bit at school, but mostly with (very) basic search engines and text search.

I found another thread, where a guy was told to use either os.rename or shutil.move. I made a simple test with os.rename:

```
os.rename("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/desination/for/file.foo")
```

And it works, so far so good.

**Is there any way to make python run through every file from a folder and move it into a corresponding subdirectory in another folder?** The original directory contains all the files, while the target directory contains all the folders.

Every file (A_file, B_file, etc.) has the same name as the folder(A_folder, B_folder, etc), which means they are in the correct order.

This makes me think a simple iteration could work, as in(More of an algorithm than code):

```
for file in original_dir
    move file to folder_x in tar_dir
    x += 1
```

Obviously this is not complete, but maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Remember to not tell anyone at work about this script so you can have 10 minutes (or however long it used to take) to do whatever you want. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes directories recursively.

```
os.makedirs(path)
```

So you pass the path to the directory you want. eg /path/to/
Which you would follow up with the copy.

```
def move_file(new_path_to_file, file_to_move):
  file_name = file_to_move.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
  os.makedirs(new_path_to_file)
  os.rename(file_to_move, os.path.join(new_path_to_file, file_name))
```

You could also make it easier by passing in the filename as well.

Comment: Hi Jase,
Thanks for the quick answer. I managed to work it work with something very similar :-)